# How can one solve the infinite loop of change events?

Tags: vba, excel

I am having an issue with the Change event in general:

I have designed a Userform and Worksheet which is updated if the user changes something like a filter or cells ect.

The problem is now the following:

If something is changed, the change event is triggered and changes some things (cells, lists, filter ect.) and this triggers the same event. Like this you will get an infinite loop of change events. My current solution is the follwing:

```
Public EventsEnabled as boolean

Sub Change_Event()
If EnableEvents Then
EnableEvents=False
   enter code which cannot triggers Change_Event here
End If
EnableEvents=True
End Sub
```

So basically I am bypassing this issue by enableing and disabling the change events I use by myself.

Now the question: Is this the best solution or is there something easier, faster or more elegant then this?

Comment: Do you need to check that events are enabled? If they aren't, would this code even be running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IMO this is the most reliable solution, provided you change your code to:

```
Public EventsDisabled as boolean

Sub Change_Event()
If EventsDisabled Then Exit Sub
EventsDisabled=True
   enter code which cannot triggers Change_Event here
EventsDisabled=False
End Sub
```

These changes ensure your event works when the VBA project is reset.

Answer (score 0):

Put `Application.EnableEvents = False` inside your `Worksheet_Change` sub before running your code.  When your code is finished, turn events back on with `Application.EnableEvents = True`.

This prevents Excel from firing events (like Worksheet_Change) while your code is running.